# How to store selected button in params?

Tags: html, css, ruby, sinatra

I'm pretty new to programming ,  I'm writing a simple Rock Paper Scissors game. there are 3 buttons with pictures, depending on which one is clicked by the player, the next page should show that picture. In other words, If the player clicks the "rock" button, then it should be shown on the next page.
The problem is that I can't figure out how to store the selected button so that it can show up in '/results' rout.

```html
(play.erb)

        <div class="pbox-1">
        <form action=/choice method="post">
          <input type="image" src="images/rock.jpg"  name="rock" />
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="pbox-2">
        <form action=/choice method="post">
          <input type="image" src="images/paper.jpg"  name="paper" />
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="pbox-3">
        <form action=/choice method="post">
          <input type="image" src="images/scissors.jpg"  name="scissors" />
        </form>
        </div>
```

```rb
(controller)

require 'sinatra/base'
require './lib/game'
require './lib/player'

class Rps < Sinatra::Base
    enable :sessions

    get '/play' do
        erb :play
    end

    post '/choice' do
        redirect '/results'
    end

    get '/results' do
        erb :results
    end

    run! if app_file == $0
end
```

```rb
(Player class)

require_relative 'game'

class Player
    attr_reader :name, :choice
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        @choice = nil
    end
    def make_choice(player_choice)
        @choice = player_choice
    end
end
```

```rb
(Game class)

require_relative 'player'

class Game
    attr_reader :players 
    def initialize(player_1)
        @players = player_1
    end
    def player_1
        @players
    end
    def player_1_choice
        player_1.choice
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a hidden field in each of the forms, like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="choice" value="rock" />
```

Then in your `post '/choice'` function you can access it with `params[:choice]`.